# Problem when using two different shaders

Tags: opengl, c++, glsl

I have created a simple shader for drawing my scene in OpenGL. When another shader was introduced, a problem appeared.

I use the first shader and draw few objects in the scene. Then I use the second shader and draw something else. Every draw call has it's `glUseProgram()` before the drawing starts. Problem is that all my objects drawn with the first shader disappear, but if I call `glUseProgram(firstShader)` right after the second drawing is finished everything is fine. I can't figure out why this is happening even if I'm calling `glUseProgram(firstShader)` right before the drawing starts.

Is there something I'm missing about OpenGL drawing process? Is it possible that OpenGL actually draws everything using the second shader?

Most simplified version of my program looks something like this:

```
glClear(...);

glUseProgam(simpleStandardShader); // just transforming vertices and doing some directional lighting and texturing
foreach (GameObject)
    glDrawArray(...); // draw all 3D objects

glUseProgram(spriteShader); // transforming quads in screen space and texturing
foreach(Sprite)
    glDrawArray(...); // draw all quads

glSwapBuffers(); // i hope i wrote it right, don't remember exact name
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Is this `glUseShader` your custom function, or did you actually mean `glUseProgram`?

Comment: @concept3d It's very object oriented so it will be hard to actually upload relevant parts without uploading bunch of code.

Comment: @glampert Yeah, my bad. I was writing this half asleep. I corrected it.

Comment: Switching shaders shouldn't have the effect you are describing, and the problem probably lies elsewhere. Maybe you are accidentally clearing your framebuffer. Regardless, without seeing the code for how you are setting up your draw calls, it's hard to help.

Comment: @Fault Is there any way that my second shader is clearing buffer at the and of everything? Second shader is just drawing quads on the screen (simulating 2D graphics for HUD). It works fine, i can draw for example little image on the top left corner, but if I don't reactivate first shader right after that, scene is lost, only image remains. I'm not at home right now, I'll try to upload something later. For now I'll add very simplified version of my code.

Comment: Are you setting any uniforms before calling glUseProgram?

Comment: @GuyRT I don't have access to the code right now, but maybe. Is that relevant?

Comment: I asked because you say "...if I call glUseProgram(firstShader) right after the second drawing is finished everything is fine". That lead me to think that (without that call) on the subsequent frame uniforms are being set on the second program before the first one is selected again.

Comment: @GuyRT I tried already to put activation of first shader on top of the draw method but nothing changed. After drawing with second shader I'm not setting any uniforms until next frame, when the first shader is already being activated.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference between setting it at the end of one frame and setting it at the beginning of the next. I think the problem must lie somewhere else.

Comment: @GuyRT Ok, I got my hand on the code at last. Well, it appears that I truly WAS setting uniforms for currently non-active shader (first shader). Everything is fine now. Thanks for help. If you want post your answer and I'll mark it.